# What is the word for the military unit that provides communication service in battlefield?

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for the word for a military unit that provides the communication service in the battlefield. This unit has to transport, encrypt and decrypt information for other units in the battlefield.

Comment: I'd try searching for "signal corps", "field signal battalion", "signal troops".

Comment: a military word for this unit is scout

Comment: @pazzo - please provide a reference for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This unit, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_corps), is called "Signal corps" or "Corps of signals":

> A signal corps is a military branch, responsible for military communications (signals). Many countries maintain a signal corps, which is typically subordinate to a country's army.
>   Military communication usually consists of radio, telephone, and digital communications.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify how large a unit is being discussed. Just as an infantry unit can be anywhere from a fire team (4 persons in the US Army) to a division (up to 20,000 for the US), a signal unit (or signals unit for the Brits) can be of various sizes. In terms of numbered units, these range from companies to commands (equivalent to division). Generally, a signal brigade supports a corps (a collection of divisions). The smallest signal unit is the section, equivalent more or less to a platoon.

There is no such unit as the Signal Corps. The Signal Corps is a branch, not a unit.